# Angular 1.4 View Encapsulation and Shadow DOM - is it possible?

Tags: angularjs, polymer, encapsulation, shadow-dom

I am in the process of changing my app from using Polymer to Angular 1.4 for stability reasons. Because of my familiarity with Polymer and web components (and future use of Angular 2) I am choosing to architect my app using the [Component Pattern](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHMO_enUS505US505&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=angular%20component%20pattern).

I have searched and thus far only come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874926/angularjs-directive-how-to-encapsulate-css) and the solution was a no longer maintained github repo. I want to know if it is possible to have view encapsulation with Angular 1.4. In case I am misstating, specifically, can my directives with templates have their own encapsulated styles like is done in [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html) and Angular 2 without relying on Grunt?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is. I am using Angular 1.6 in my test, but I was able to get shadow DOM working inside an angular directive including bindings.

Here is my sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular 1.x ShadowDOM example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('myElController', ($scope) => {

    });

    var template = `
    <style>
    :host {
      left: 50%;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      border: 1px solid black;
      box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 6px 12px;
    }

    h3 {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
      margin: 0 -12px 8px;
      padding: 0 12px 8px;
    }

    p {
      margin: 0;
    }
    </style>
        <h3>{{title}}</h3>
      <p>{{info}}</p>
    `;

    app.directive('myEl', ($compile) => {
        return {
          "restrict": "E",
          "controller": "myElController",
          "template": '',
          "scope": {
            "title": "@",
            "info": "@"
          },
          "link": function($scope, $element) {
            console.log('here');
            $scope.shadowRoot = $element[0].attachShadow({mode:'open'});
            $scope.shadowRoot.innerHTML = template;
            $compile($scope.shadowRoot)($scope);
          }
        };
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <my-el title="This is a title" info="This is the info of the element"></my-el>
    </div>
    <div class="shell">
      <h3>Outside title (H3)</h3>
      <p>Outside content (P)</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The trick is to not have a default template for the directive. Just us an empty string. Then, in the `link` function you would create the shadow root and set it's innerHTML to your real template. Then you need to run `$compile` on the shadow root to bind it back to the directive's $scope.

> Be aware that this will only work on a browser that natively supports shadow DOM. Any Polyfill will not support real CSS encapsulation. For that it is better to use a form of BEM CSS: http://getbem.com/introduction/